# Running gradlew produces ": No such file or directory"

Tags: 12.04, files, vagrant

We are two developers running Vagrant VMs with Ubuntu 12.04 installed. Running `./gradlew` to execute our build script works fine for me, but when he runs the same command he gets the error: `: No such file or directory`.

I have googled this to the max but all solutions are related to running a 32-bit executable on a 64-bit system but we are running 32-bit Ubuntu. Since we do this immediately after creating the VM from a provisioning script, the machines should be identical. The only differences I can think of are external, he runs Vagrant from Windows while I run it from OS X.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post the proper error? and the script files including vagrant and gradlew

Answer (score 5):

Seems like the line endings are not in Unix style (LF).

Open the file in vi and type `set fileformat=unix`.
Then save `:w` and try again.

Comment: To be more clear in step by step :

Comment: To be more clear  first type vi gradlew then :set fileformat=unix then :w and then :q

Comment: I gave an upvote since this is a good suggestion. But I didn't accept the answer since I could not verify it, by then the problem was no longer relevant.